# How do I get a PHP script to feed data into JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, json, sqlite

I have the following data currently feeding JQuery Autocomplete

```
 var network_autocomplete=[
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];

            $( "#network" ).autocomplete({
                source: network_autocomplete
            });
```

I need to modify this to retrieve the array of results from a php page. Can somebody help me to modify this so I can in JavaScript do this?

```
network_autocomplete=data
```

Currently, the code retrieves data from an SQLite table in this manner:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/bacnet.db');
    $query = "SELECT net, name,  FROM network";

    foreach ($db->query($query) as $row) {
        $networks[] = array('net' => $row['net']);
    }

    echo json_encode($networks);
    return json_encode($networks);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Could not connect to the database'));
}
```

Comment: SELECT net, name,  FROM network have  unuse comma , change to SELECT net, name  FROM network

Comment: Why you echo and return at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$networks[] = array('net' => $row['net']);` to
`$networks[] = $row['net'];`
And you should not have return, unless this is a function (and if it's a function, why it has an echo?)

Answer (score 0):

What I do when i need this is put some PHP directly in the javascript, so

```
foreach ($db->query($query) as $row) {
   $networks[] = '{ label: "blah", value: "' . $row['net'] . '" }';
}
$autocomplete = implode(",",$networks);
```

Then inside the script you can do,

```
var network_autocomplete = [$autocomplete];
$( "#network" ).autocomplete({
    source: network_autocomplete
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: If there’s *any chance at all* that the data could contain quotes or other non-JavaScript-string-friendly characters, concatenating strings together like this could break, or, at worst, leave you open to XSS attacks. Use `json_encode`, its output is perfectly OK to embed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the folowing:

```
<?php
$values = array("'foo'", "'bar'", "'baz'"); ?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var network_autocomplete = [
          <?php echo join(",", $values) ?>
        ];
    ...
</script>
```